# Distribution divergence and moment distance

Tags: probability

It is well-known that under some conditions, a distribution can be uniquely determined by its moments. What I'm curious about, is that suppose two distributions $P_1$, $P_2$ have very similar moments of all orders, namely

$|m_1^1 - m_1^2| < \delta_1$

$|m_2^1 - m_2^2| < \delta_2$

...

$|m_n^1 - m_n^2| < \delta_n$

where $m_a^b$ means the $a^{th}$ moment of the $b^{th}$ distribution, and $\delta_k$ is a small quantity. Then intuitively $P_1$ and $P_2$ should be very "close" to each other. So is there any theorem that states some divergence (say KL or Hellinger divergence) between $P_1$ and $P_2$ can be upper-bounded by a function of $\delta_k, k=1\ldots...n$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think there is any general bound of this form, unless you add restrictions on the family $P_1$, $P_2$ belong to (eg, mixture of Gaussians, or unimodal, or whatever). A lot of recent work in statistical estimation/CS relies on proving such structural results (see eg. [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4223v1.pdf), which includes a main technical lemma the fact that if the distance between two mixtures of Gaussians is big, then it must be the case that the distance between one of their first six moments is "not too small").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lower bound which couples the moments of $P_2$ with the mean of $P_1$ is Kullback's inequality for KL divergence (but not in a clean way in terms of the $\delta$'s - there are other simple lower bounds for KL divergence such as in terms of TV distance ). However, you can find distributions where the moments are arbitrarily close and the K-L divergence $D(P_1 || P_2)$ is infinite.

Let $P_1$ take on the value $0$ with probability $1$, and $P_2$ take on the value $0< c << 1$ with probability $1$. Then the KL divergence is infinite, but the $\delta_k$'s can be chosen to be small for appropriate values of $c$ (you could use scaled and shifted Bernoulli's or something else if you want a less trivial example - if the supports are disjoint, the KL divergence will always be infinite (or if the support of $P_1$ strictly contains the support of $P_2$).

Likely, you want to impose some additional constraints, which can give nice bounds. For example, the Hellinger distance is easily bounded in terms of the TV distance. A neat example (along with a link to Verdu's recent ITA paper) is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160369/are-gaussians-with-different-moments-far-in-total-variation-distance) for the case of Gaussians where the covariance matrix differs entrywise by at most $\delta$.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this Kullback's inequality for KL divergence ?